# presentViewController: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue ' - how to handle 2 segues from the same ViewController

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

I'm getting an exception the second time I try to present my view controller and I'm hoping folks on this list can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong...

My storyboard has a navigationController that loads a CategoryViewController. In  CategoryViewController UI (a UICollectionViewController) A segue is connected to the cell to load another view controller.

When a click occurs on the cell, the performSegue in my CategoryViewController is called (so far so good) and I then reload the same view controller as follow:

```
//check if item has a second category or not
if (/*need to reload same controller with different data*/) {
        //Load list of items for that category
        //CategoryViewController *v= [segue destinationViewController];

        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryViewID"];
        CategoryViewController *cvc = (CategoryViewController*)vc;
        // do some into on cvc here

        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }
```

this works fine. Now, once the second instance of CategoryViewController is loaded and displayed and I click on a cell, performSegue is called again and the second part of the if statement is executed where I try to load another viewController something around the lines of the following is executed:

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryViewerID"];
 CategoryViewerController *cvc = (CategoryViewerController*)vc;
 vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

My new viewController gets instantiated but after that I get the following runtime error:
reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showCategoryList'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: the only difference i am able to make out between the two is, in one loop you are pushing the view controller and in the other you are presenting it.. so try to push the latter part of the view controller where you are getting the exception!

Comment: nope sorry - tried that but got the same issue. somehow my first call that pushes the new view controller must mess up the hierarchy - I tried to add a new segue that loads a new controller view in the storyboard but i get the same issue then...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to make this work.

There is a great sample code from DTS that shows how to use segue and shows how to setup multiple segues from 1 view controller:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UnwindSegue/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013644

The first segue is connected from the cellID to itself (ctrl-click drag from the cell ID to the controller at the bottom of the scene) - the second segue is connected from the controller to the second scene in my storyboard.

In the code I implemented shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and return false when I don't want a new "same controller" to be created.

I use as shown in the sample code didSelectItemAtIndexPath to trigger the second segue by calling performSegueWithIdentifier when the right conditions are met in my controller.

there is still one mystery: the navigation controller is now between my rootViewController and the my second viewController. I'll have to try to move it back where I had it originally to see if this changes the behavior of the app and generates the runtime error again...